# Vaadin Compile widgets(addons)

Tags: java, gwt, liferay, widget, vaadin

I need some help compiling the widgets of my vaadin project. I have downloaded an addon ([FormSender](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/formsender)) , because it an client-side component i have to [Compile my wingets](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/addons.compiling.html), when i click the Vaadin widgets compile button in eclipse, i get the following message :

```
Compiling widgetset com.example.vaadinproject.widgetset.VaadinprojectWidgetset
Updating GWT module description file...
Sep 28, 2011 10:32:50 AM com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.ClassPathExplorer getAvailableWidgetSets
INFO: Widgetsets found from classpath:
    org.vaadin.hene.popupbutton.widgetset.PopupbuttonWidgetset in jar:file:/home/s2padmin/workspace/VaadinProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/popupbutton-1.2.1.jar!/
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet in jar:file:/home/s2padmin/workspace/VaadinProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/vaadin-6.6.0.jar!/
    com.example.vaadinproject.widgetset.VaadinprojectWidgetset in file:/home/s2padmin/workspace/VaadinProject/src
    org.vaadin.risto.formsender.widgetset.FormsenderWidgetset in jar:file:/home/s2padmin/workspace/VaadinProject/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/formsender-0.1.jar!/

Sep 28, 2011 10:32:50 AM com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.ClassPathExplorer getAvailableWidgetSets
INFO: Search took 28ms
Done.
Starting GWT compiler
Sep 28, 2011 10:33:16 AM com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.ClassPathExplorer getPaintablesHavingWidgetAnnotation
INFO: Searching for paintables..
Sep 28, 2011 10:33:17 AM com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.widgetsetutils.ClassPathExplorer getPaintablesHavingWidgetAnnotation
INFO: Search took 1075ms
Widgetset compilation completed
```

it looks good so far, a new file is being made in my project "widgetset.gwt.xml" it contains :

```
inherits name="org.vaadin.risto.formsender.widgetset.FormsenderWidgetset"
```

but its not working ... i get the following message in my portlet :

> Widgetset does not contain implementation for
>   org.vaadin.risto.formsender.FormSender. Check its @ClientWidget
>   mapping, widgetsets GWT module description file and re-compile your
>   widgetset. In case you have downloaded a vaadin add-on package, you
>   might want to refer to add-on instructions. Unrendered UIDL:
>   org.vaadin.risto.formsender.FormSender(NO CLIENT IMPLEMENTATION FOUND)
>   id=PID7

Im working with eclipse, have liferay portal installed +vaadin addon.

have anyone seen something like this? is it because of liferay or something else , i have tryed lots of addons , but none of them is working.

Comment: Did you modify your web.xml? To add the widgetset param.

Comment: dont have to do it. its being made by the eclipse vaadin plugin (checked it)

Comment: Check the version of Vaadin (in your project and in liferay) and the version of GWT. And did you package the widget's jar file with your war?

Comment: do you mean the projects widgets set package ? its being made  by the plugin to , actuayly everything is being made by the plugin. i just have to click one button and it should work as the guide says ...

Comment: I'm not aware of liferay, but if you are using eclipse wtp (integrated server of eclipse) you could check after starting the server if the plugins jar is present under this path:  $<workspace_folder>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\$<project_folder>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded an liferay plugin wich compiles the Vaadin addons.I was running my application as a portlet on Liferay , so i needed to compile the shared widgetset on Liferay , the compile button of Vaadins eclipse plugin compiled the widgets to the project not to the Portal itself.

Addon :

[Vaadin Control Panel for Liferay](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/vaadin-control-panel-for-liferay)

Comment: Yeah, with Liferay, your Vaadin widgetset is not portlet-specific but application-specific. I used to do the widgetset copying manually, but that Control Panel addon looks quite useful.